# How to set a placeholder for select drop down

Tags: php, html

I am trying to set a placeholder (like 'Choose...' or something similar) for my select drop down. I know how that would work in a 'static' drop down. However, I do not how that works in a database acquired drop down.
**My code**:

```
<label>Please choose an event:</label>
  <select id="select-event-type">
     <?php foreach ($this->events as $event) {
         echo "<option value='" .$event->event_id. "'>" .$event->event_title."</option>";
      }?>
</select>
```

Everything works fine. I just would like when the drop down loads that it says 'Choose...' instead of my first entry from my database and that the placeholder cannot be selected anymore after opening the drop down.
I am really new to this and I am very thankful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put the option before your loop.

```
<label>Please choose an event:</label>

<select id="select-event-type">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <?php foreach ($this->events as $event) {
        echo "<option value='" .$event->event_id. "'>" .$event->event_title."</option>";
    }?>
</select>
```

Comment: Haha!! That was easy! Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

```
<label>Please choose an event:</label>
  <select id="select-event-type">
     <?php 
      echo "<option selected>Choose...</option>";
      foreach ($this->events as $event) {
         echo "<option value='" .$event->event_id. "'>" .$event->event_title."</option>";
      }?>
</select>
```